# iterate over list in python using condition and choices

Tags: python-3.x, list, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu56w.png)

I have data in this format and now if below conditions are true then i want to put a name in category column,
if,
two is having no 5,
three is having no 2 or 3
six is having no 3,

then my category should be fire tv.

I tool two,three,six column in to lists and zip it and saved in list4,

code:

```
b=[]
a=[]
for (i,j,k) in list4:
  if (list4[i]==5)& (list4[j]==2|3) & (list4[k]==3):
    print(i,j,k)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please supply a **[mcve]**, i.e. no images/links, just text.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier to answer if you gave a desired input and output. But by the looks of it your are looking for something like this:

```
mask = (df.two.apply(lambda x: 5 in x if type(x)=='list' else x == 5) | \ 
       (df.three.apply(lambda x: 2 in x if type(x)=='list' else x == 2) | \
       (df.three.apply(lambda x: 3 in x if type(x)=='list' else x == 3) | \
       (df.six.apply(lambda x: 3 in x if type(x)=='list' else x == 3))

df['category'] = np.nan
df.loc[mask,'category'] = 'fire tv'
```

Comment: as Category column is having value 0, its giving error ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer, also column two,three,six is of type series which is not iterable

Comment: My bad, as you have `NaN` values in your `six` column, you can't always iterate of them, so you have to test the type of the value in the cell first. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: now...code is running without error but in category ''fire tv' is not there. In actual 20 columns should have this label.

Comment: we are missing somewhere...though the conditions are true, we are getting ans

Comment: I didn't see you had lists in columns `two`and `three`as well, I edited my answer accordingly. Although, there might be a smarter way to deal with the multiple conditions in the column `three`

Comment: yeah actually...i guess in each column only 1st value its checking. its not checking values after comma(,) so loop not getting the desired combination.

Comment: Any idea on this?

Comment: I suspect the issue comes from the fact that your non list values weren't checked. Try the new mask, hope it works fine.

Comment: Can you run df.dtypes and tell me what the outcome is? If your columns `two` `three` and `six` contain strings instead of lists, you will have to do it otherwise. Using `re` module for instance.

Comment: tem_list = []
for x in list_7:
    if ('5' in x[0]) & ('2'in x[1] or'3'in x[1]) & ('3' in x[2]):
        tem_list.append('Fire TV')
    else:
        tem_list.append(None)

Comment: here is the solution